# Где хранить музыку?

Tags: javascript, c#, музыка

Я начинаю писать дипломную работу на тему "Стриминговый сервис". Сначала подумал, что было бы круто арендовать веб сервер, на котором буду хранить музыку, но это как-то дорого, да и незачем, т.к потом возникла идея хранить все на гугл диске.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь смог сделать следующее: поиск существующей музыки в коллекции, добавление музыки в свой альбом. Если пользователь не найдет какую-либо песню, у него есть возможность самостоятельно добавить ее на гугл диск (в приложение).
Я надеюсь, гугл апи позволит реализовать это все.

Что вы думаете по этому поводу? Что бы вы использовали вместо гугл диска?

Comment: Если сервер -- дорого, то возьмите недорогой сервер. Есть же какая-то граница, за которой у вас будет считаться, что недорого? Ну пара долларов в месяц -- это долго? Вряд ли дольше семестра понадобится держать сервер. Кроме того, вполне  возможно, что подобные бесплатные сервисы имеют прямые запреты в лицензионных соглашениях на использование сервиса не по назначению и могут на этом основании курсовую зарубить.

Comment: Блин, это курсовой проект - по-моему, уровень не предполагает создания реально работающего сервиса. Всё одно - создал, показал, сдал, забыл. Вполне достаточно, если он будет работать в рамках локальной сети - ему ж параллельно, серые адреса или не очень. Так что минимальной локалки, даже в рамках VMM, вполне достаточно - положить десяток песен, показать, что можно создать юзера, сунуть ему в один плейлист две песни, в другой три, послушать плейлист или отдельную песню, искать по атрибутам, и закачать одиннадцатую...

Comment: А у яндекс-диска есть WebDAV.

Comment: Да возьмите где-нибудь vds на пробный период за месяц до сдачи - денег не потратите, и сервер для хранения будет. А до этого момента потестить локально можно.

Comment: ошибся, извините. не курсовой, а дипломная работа

Comment: @penancewarrior И чё, вот прям на защите всё вот это будешь показывать? смотрите, как я песню закачиваю по 10 килобайт в секунду...

Comment: @Qwertiy Яндекс достаточно быстро всё банит, если видит какой-нибудь подвох...

Comment: Да хоть прямо на домашнем компьютере. У меня ноутбук круглосуточно включен, полтерабайта данных с него раздаю разными путями

Comment: @andreymal, нужен белый ip от провайдера. Если есть, то отлично, если нет - то так себе идея.

Comment: @Qwertiy Есть, вроде, сервис, который мапит через клиентскую программу свой внешний IP на ПК пользователя и передает трафик.

Comment: @iluxa1810, вроде такой только для игр был. Ну или опять же платно. Он не мапит, он держит открытое соединение. Хотя, я тут начинаю вспоминать, что есть 2 вида NAT'а и один из них действительно позволяет мапить порт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы для тестов запустил локальный сервер на собственном компьютере. Прекрасно подойдёт к примеру XAMPP, там есть и FTP и в довесок HTTP с MySQL (те мб. тоже когда нибудь да пригодятся). Устанавливается и настраивается это быстро и легко. Удачи!

Comment: При локальном компе основные сложности с отсутствием белого ip, а не с настройкой сервера.

Comment: У топикстартера выбран стек на базе C#, XAMPP не под это заточен вроде?

Comment: @AK в состав XAMPP входит FileZilla (если не перепутал название) это FTP-сервер. Соответственно к нему можно подключиться используя что угодно, что поддерживает этот протокол передачи данных.

Comment: @Qwertiy когда тестируешь на локальном компе белый IP ни к чему, подключаешься по внутреннему IP (там будет что то вроде 192.168.0.1:21 или 172.0.0.1:21). Белый IP необходим для подключения к серверу других компьютеров, причем тех что не находятся в локальной сети (те что находятся тоже могут подключиться по внутреннему IP, нужно будет только привязку MAC адреса в настройках роутера сделать). P.S.: Даже если понадобится, белый IP стоит около 150р в год если не ошибаюсь (мб и месяц), это копейки.